# Creation of CDATA section is confusing

Tags: java, xml, cdata

I am trying to create CDATA section within the description field, but failing. The code is pretty simple, but in the resulting XML a CDATA section does not appear!!

```java
Node de = document.createElement("description");
de.appendChild(document.createCDATASection(reportData.getIssue().getDescription() + "more]]>data"));
e.appendChild(de);
```

In the result XML, I'm getting:

```xml
<description>Room #1128 has AD issues.more]]&gt;data</description>
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Why are you placing `]]>` in the text? Surely the `createCDATASection` will generate that too?

Comment: Doesn't matter! I want to see CDATA in resulting XML, where is it?

Comment: The problem is that if you put "&gt;" in a CDATA-section, you're going to get "&gt;" not ">" when it is interpreted back. What you're seeing is pretty much the only way to preserve the ">"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence `]]>` terminates a CDATA section and thus cannot appear within a CDATA section.

Your XML library is recovering by ditching the CDATA section and using entities for characters that would have special meaning.

Since `<foo><![CDATA[Hello, world>]]></foo>` and `<foo>Hello, world&gt;</foo>` are equivalent, this isn't a problem (unless someone tries to parse the resulting XML with a tool that isn't an XML parser, which way lies madness).

Comment: So you saying DOM4j is smart enough to figure out that CDATA section not needed in this case?

Comment: Not so much "not needed" as "invalid".

Comment: I wouldn't call it "invalid". If the string inside CDATA contains a "]]>" a proper CDATA implementation should divide the string into two CDATA sections.

Comment: Why I dont see any CDATA section? What would be resulting XML if my code will be:
   de.appendChild(document.createCDATASection(reportData.getIssue().getDescription()));

Comment: As my answer says, you don't see a CDATA section because you can't store the data you have using a CDATA section.

Answer (score 7):

You should specify CDATA section element(s).

You can do it like this;

```
 transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "tagName");
```

if you want to specify more than one CDATA section element use white space as delimiter.

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "tagName1 tagName2");
```

Full Code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("catalog");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

Element description = doc.createElement("description");
description.appendChild(doc.createCDATASection("/&(*/**SOME STRANGE DESCRIPTION**ĞĞÜ656*9/*9^+%3ÜĞPÜ"));
rootElement.appendChild(description);

Element books = doc.createElement("books");
rootElement.appendChild(books);

Element book = doc.createElement("book");
books.appendChild(book);

Element author = doc.createElement("author");
author.appendChild(doc.createCDATASection("&/(&/(QNzxB5yiBibGj2MM ÇÖÇÇ"));
book.appendChild(author);

Element price = doc.createElement("price");
price.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("50.5"));
book.appendChild(price);

Element title = doc.createElement("title");
title.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("my book title"));
book.appendChild(title);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "description author descr");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Result will be like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
   <description><![CDATA[/&(*/**SOME STRANGE DESCRIPTION**ĞĞÜ656*9/*9^+%3ÜĞPÜ]]></description>
   <books>
      <book>
         <author><![CDATA[&/(&/(QNzxB5yiBibGj2MM ÇÖÇÇ]]></author>
         <price>50.5</price>
         <title>my book title</title>
      </book>
   </books>
</catalog>
```

If we want to apply your exact sample (with your data + "]]");

```
String someInfo = "example-info";
Element dscr = doc.createElement("descr");
dscr.appendChild(doc.createCDATASection(someInfo + "more]]>data"));
book.appendChild(dscr);
```

Then result will be like this;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <catalog>
       <description><![CDATA[/&(*/**SOME STRANGE DESCRIPTION**ĞĞÜ656*9/*9^+%3ÜĞPÜ]]></description>
       <books>
          <book>
             <author><![CDATA[&/(&/(QNzxB5yiBibGj2MM ÇÖÇÇ]]></author>
             <price>50.5</price>
             <title>my book title</title>
             <descr><![CDATA[example-infomore]]]]><![CDATA[>data]]></descr>
          </book>
       </books>
    </catalog>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below method:

```
CDATASection cdata = document.createCDATASection("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a `>` in the XML Data.
It's being escaped into `&gt;` (greater than)

Notice that the *Greater Than* sign will mess up your `</description>` tag because its the beginning of an end tag.

You can read about it [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/31/qanda.html) (among other places)

Comment: I think my case it specific implementaion, my point is if I asked to create CDATA section, why it is not in resulting XML?